# Cannot find method on button click event in ag-grid with Angular2

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, ag-grid

I want to call editAsset() method on **button's** click event in **ag-grid**.

**ListComponent :**

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.route.data.forEach((data: { assets: Asset[]}) => {
            this.gridOptions.columnDefs = this.createColumnDefs(data.assets[0]);
            this.gridOptions.rowData = data.assets
        });
  }

private createColumnDefs(asset) {
        let keyNames = Object.keys(asset);
        let headers = []
        keyNames.filter(key => key != '__v' && key != '_id').map(key => {
            headers.push({
                headerName: key,
                field: key,
                width: 100
            })
        });

        headers.push({
            headerName: 'update',
            field: 'update',
            cellRendererFramework: {
                template: '<button (click) = "editAsset()"> Edit </button>'
            },
            width: 100
        });
        return headers;
    }

  editAsset(): void {
    alert("here");
  }
```

Both of these are defined in the same component.

But it can't find the method and showing the following error :

[**Here's the Snapshot of error report**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vaxvx.png)

[**Here's the grid**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pY4sG.png)

Comment: Please post more code. What is the `DynamicComponent`?

Comment: @mxii Okk. And DynamicComponent is some class in @angular/compile/...

Comment: I assume its not working cause the button is created dynamically and not via angular2.. but i cant say for sure. to less code to reproduce it..

Comment: @AkshayRana did you find any solution for this?